# Can this be done without reading file twice? C++

Tags: c++

What im doing here in main.cpp is reading a text file twice: once to remove the '\' from each path name, and again to supply the original name of the file to the SetPath() in my implementation File.

```
// This a read file sub-routine called in the main function.
// Its purpose was intentionally set out to read the file, and pass information
// to functions to MyClassFile Implementational file.


// global varaible to have the file spec.
char MyClass::List_[ ARRY_SZ ] = {};

int main()
{

..
inFile.open( MyClass::List_, ios::in  );

    while ( inFile.peek() != '\n' )
    {
        inFile.get( ch );
        if ( ch == 92 )
            count++;
    }

    inFile.clear();
    inFile.close();

    inFile2.open( MyClass::List_, ios::in  );
    while ( inFile2.peek() != EOF )
    {
            for( unsigned short i = 0 ; i < count; i++ )
            {
                inFile2.getline( tmpArray, ENTRY_SZ, 92 );  
            }

            inFile2.getline( tmpArray, ENTRY_SZ, '\n' );
            MyObject = new MyClass( tmpArray );  // Name W/O Path   
            LinkedObject->AddLink( MyObject );
            lineCount++;
    }
    while ( inFile2.peek() != EOF )
    {
            inFile2.getline( tmpArray, ENTRY_SZ, '\n' );
            MyObject->GetPath( tmpArray ); 
    }
    inFile2.clear();
    inFile2.close();
}
```

The text file is of this format:

```
C:/temp/fileID
C:/temp/FileID2
```

I need to pass just the name to a copy constructor.
I need to pass the full path name which is still in the text file to a MyClass::GetPath() function in my Implementation file.

Is there a way to do this without reading the file twice?
I hope you can see what im trying to do here.
i can probably just rewind to the beginning or something like that

Comment: Yes, you can rewind a file pointer to the beginning; see seek(). A single-pass algorithm would be better, though. That said -- I find this question hard to parse, and the subject very nondescriptive; using the word "this" is not useful when someone is trying to determine whether a question is worth their time based on a one-line summary.

Comment: Using (ch == 92) is a bad sign.  Use: (ch == '\\')

Answer (score 8):

Restating the problem:

- I have a text file where each line contains a Windows-style absolute path name.
- I need to pass the basename of the file to a constructor and the full name to another function.

*Can I do this without rereading the file?*

The answer is yes.

- Read each line into a string (so it contains the full path).
- If necessary, strip the trailing newline.
- From the full path, create a new string containing just the basename of the file.
- Call the constructor with the basename.
- Call the other function with the pathname.

This is slightly more string manipulation - it is vastly less file manipulation, and that is what costs performance.

Use `'\\'` rather than 92 throughout.